# Given a set of bounded functions, how to prove it is a Banach algebra?

Tags: functional-analysis

Hi there I am trying to solve this question

> Let $V$ be a space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the 2-norm $‖f‖_2^2=∫_0^1|f|^2$. For a continuous function $φ$ on $[0,1]$, define a linear map $M_φ:V⟶V$ by $M_φf=φf$.
>
> > Is $\mathcal{A}$$=${$M_φ│φ∈C([0,1])$} a Banach algebra?

I know that Banach algebra is a normed algebra whose underlying normed space is Banach. From my previous work, I have that $M_φ$ is bounded and $‖M_φ‖=‖φ‖_∞$. It follows that $\forall$ $x,y∈$$\mathcal{A}$, $‖x⋅y‖_∞≤‖x‖_∞ ‖y‖_∞$.

However, since $V$ is an incomplete normed linear space, I can't simply show that the underlying normed space is Banach. If possible, could you please elaborate on how can I bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that $\|M_{\phi}\|=\|\phi\|_{\infty}$ shows that the space $\mathcal A$ with the operator norm is isometrically isomorphic to $C[0,1]$ with the usual sup norm. So this space is complete.

Comment: Thank you I understand now!